# Catching PHP exceptions in Flex without AMFPHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flex4, amfphp

I'm looking for a way to catch an Exception thrown by PHP in Flex using `HTTPService`. Is it possible to do it **without using AMFPHP**?

In my current implementation, if an Exception is thrown in PHP, a `FaultEvent.FAULT` is indeed dispatched on Flex side. The only problem is that the exception's message string is nowhere to be found in `FaultEvent`.

Let me try to explain better with the help of an example. Let us say we have the following PHP code on server side:

```
<?php
  throw new Exception("Exception message");
?>
```

On flex side, say there is an `HTTPService` instance which calls the above PHP code. Moreover, it calls the following function on `FaultEvent.FAULT`:

```
private function onFaultyResult(evt:FaultEvent):void {
  //How do I get the exception message here?    
}
```

How can I get the exception message from PHP in this function?

Note: `trace(evt.toString())` gives:

```
[FaultEvent fault=[RPC Fault faultString="HTTP request error" faultCode="Server.Error.Request" faultDetail="Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: 192.168.1.119/exception.php"]. URL: 192.168.1.119/exception.php"] messageId="7FF021A3-8C83-CB14-081D-8C8438802204" type="fault" bubbles=false cancelable=true eventPhase=2]
```

I also looked for "Exception message" in other fields of `evt` in the debugger but couldn't find it.

Thank you

Comment: RTFM: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/events/FaultEvent.html

Comment: @nikc: This is what trace(evt.toString) shows:

[FaultEvent fault=[RPC Fault faultString="HTTP request error" faultCode="Server.Error.Request" faultDetail="Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://192.168.1.119/flex_ssh2_exception.php"]. URL: http://192.168.1.119/flex_ssh2_exception.php"] messageId="07CC2B64-D064-8EB3-CF6D-8C74D4BE7125" type="fault" bubbles=false cancelable=true eventPhase=2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root problem is that Flash can't handle server retuns a status <> 200 http://www.robsondesign.com/blog/index.php/2009/04/16/flex-flash-and-http-status-codes/